# Run python using local interpreter whilst connected to a remote SSH connection on vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, gpu, cpu, hpc

I often connect to a remote server (HPC) that I use for GPU heavy tasks. I would like to run some python scripts located on there using my local computer's cpu as the cpu access is very limited on the remote machine.

Is it possible to change interpreter so that I use my local cpu for some tasks?